# Using skimage.transform.rescale twice on an image creates additional channels

Tags: python, reshape, scikit-image, autoencoder

In a coursera guided project that I was doing, the instructor used

```
from skimage.transform import rescale
image_rescaled = rescale(rescale(image,0.5),2.0)
```

to distort the image.

The error that is occurring on my own device (and that didn't arise on the jupyter notebook of the project, probably due to difference in versions of modules and python) was that `image_rescaled`'s number of channel's are increasing by `1`.

eg => `images_normal.shape = (256,256,256,3)` and `images_with_twice_reshape.shape=(256,256,256,4)`

This issue doesn't come up if I use `rescaled(rescale(image,2.0),0.5)`.

Is this intended in a newer version of python/skimage or am I doing something wrong?

For additional references(didn't delete anything from source code but highlighted important parts with #s):

```
import os
import re
from scipy import ndimage, misc
from skimage.transform import resize, rescale
from matplotlib import pyplot
import numpy as np

def train_batches(just_load_dataset=False):

    batches = 256 # Number of images to have at the same time in a batch

    batch = 0 # Number if images in the current batch (grows over time and then resets for each batch)
    batch_nb = 0 # Batch current index
    
    ep = 4 # Number of epochs

    images = []
    x_train_n = []
    x_train_down = []
    
    x_train_n2 = [] # Resulting high res dataset
    x_train_down2 = [] # Resulting low res dataset
    
    for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk("data/cars_train.nosync"):
        for filename in filenames:
            if re.search("\.(jpg|jpeg|JPEG|png|bmp|tiff)$", filename):
                filepath = os.path.join(root, filename)
                image = pyplot.imread(filepath)
                if len(image.shape) > 2:
                        
                    image_resized = resize(image, (256, 256)) # Resize the image so that every image is the same size
#########################
                    x_train_n.append(image_resized) # Add this image to the high res dataset
                    x_train_down.append(rescale(rescale(image_resized, 0.5), 2.0)) # Rescale it 0.5x and 2x so that it is a low res image but still has 256x256 resolution
########################
                    # >>>> x_train_down.append(rescale(rescale(image_resized, 2.0), 0.5)), this one works and gives the same shape of x_train_down and x_train_n.
########################
                    batch += 1
                    if batch == batches:
                        batch_nb += 1

                        x_train_n2 = np.array(x_train_n)
                        x_train_down2 = np.array(x_train_down)
                        
                        if just_load_dataset:
                            return x_train_n2, x_train_down2
                        
                        print('Training batch', batch_nb, '(', batches, ')')

                        autoencoder.fit(x_train_down2, x_train_n2,
                            epochs=ep,
                            batch_size=10,
                            shuffle=True,
                            validation_split=0.15)
                    
                        x_train_n = []
                        x_train_down = []
                    
                        batch = 0

    return x_train_n2, x_train_down2
```

And with the above code, I get `x_train_n2.shape = (256,256,256,3)` and `x_train_down2.shape=(256,256,256,4)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your issue as follows:

```py
import numpy as np
from skimage.transform import resize, rescale

image = np.random.random((512, 512, 3))
resized = resize(image, (256, 256))
rescaled2x = rescale(
        rescale(resized, 0.5),
        2,
)
print(rescaled2x.shape)
# prints (256, 256, 4)
```

The problem is that `resize` can infer that your final dimension is channels/RGB, because you give it a 2D shape. `rescale`, on the other hand, treats your array as a 3D image of shape (256, 256, 3), which goes down to (128, 128, 2), interpolating along the colors as well, as if they were another spatial dimension, and then upsampling to (256, 256, 4).

If you look at the [`rescale` documentation](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.transform.html#skimage.transform.rescale), you'll find the "multichannel" parameter, described as:

> Whether the last axis of the image is to be interpreted as multiple channels or another spatial dimension.

So, updating my code:

```py
rescaled2x = rescale(
        rescale(resized, 0.5, multichannel=True),
        2,
        multichannel=True,
)
print(rescaled2x.shape)
# prints (256, 256, 3)
```